# Javascript | Objects, Arrays and functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, mootools

may be you can help me. How can I create global object and function that return object values by id?

Example:

```
var chat = {
    data : {
      friends: {}
    }
}

....
/*
JSON DATA RETURNED:
{"users": [{"friend_id":"62","name":"name","username":"admin","thumb":"images/avatar/thumb_7d41870512afee28d91.jpg","status":"HI4","isonline":""},{"friend_id":"66","name":"Another name","username":"regi","thumb":"images/avatar/thumb_d3fcc14e41c3a77aa712ae54.jpg","status":"Всем привет!","isonline":"avtbsl0a6dcelkq2bd578u1qt6"},{"friend_id":"2679","name":"My name","username":"Another","thumb":"images/avatar/thumb_41effb41eb1f969230.jpg","status":"","isonline":""}]}
*/

onSuccess: function(f){
   chat.data.friends    = {};
   for(var i=0; i< f.users.length;i++){
      chat.data.friends.push(f.users[i])
   }
}
```

How can I create a new function (It will return values by friend_id)?

```
get_data_by_id: function (what, friend_id) {

/*obj.what = getfrom_globalobject(chat.data.friends???)*/
}
```

Example of use:

```
var friend_name     = get_data_by_id(name, 62);
var friend_username = get_data_by_id(username, 62);
var friend_avatar   = get_data_by_id(thumb, 62);
```

Comment: I suggest you learn how to program instead of copypasting bits of code... even the first snippet just screams "copypasted from somewhere without understanding".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
get_data_by_id: function (what, friend_id) {
   return chat.data.friends[friend_id][what];
}
```

... but use it like:

```
var friend_name     = get_data_by_id('name', 62);
```

...and set up the mapping with:

```
for(var i=0; i< f.users.length;i++){
  chat.data.friends[f.users[i].friend_id] = f.users[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `.push()` to an object. Objects are `key => value` mappings, so you need to use `char.data.friends[somekey] = f.users[i];`

If you really just want a list with numeric keys, make x5fastchat.data.friends an array: `x5fastchat.data.friends = [];`

However, since you want to be able to access the elements by `friend_id`, do the following:

```
onSuccess: function(f){
   x5fastchat.data.friends = {};
   for(var i=0; i< f.users.length;i++){
      chat.data.friends[f.users[i].friend_id] = f.users[i]
   }
}

get_data_by_id: function (what, friend_id) {
    obj[what] = chat.data.friends[friend_id][what];
}
```

Note the `obj[what]` instead of your original `obj.what`: When writing `obj.what`, `what` is handled like a string, so it's equal to `obj['what']` - but since it's a function argument you want `obj[what]`.

Comment: Nice...What about: getfrom_globalobject? Is this a function?

Comment: Or it will be:  obj[what] = chat.data.friends[friend_id][what]?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following code. You can simply copy paste it into an HTML file and open it. click "go" and you should see the result. let me know if I did not understand you correctly. :

```
<script>

myObj = { "field1" : { "key1a" : "value1a" }, "field2" : "value2" }


function go()
{

    findField(myObj, ["field2"])
    findField(myObj, ["field1","key1a"])
}


function findField( obj, fields)
{

    var myVal = obj;
    for ( var i in fields )
    {
        myVal = myVal[fields[i]]
    }

    alert("your value is [" + myVal + "]");

}
</script>


<button onclick="go()">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the friend objects rather than getting them by id and name.

```
DATA = {"users": [{"friend_id":"62","name":"name","username":"admin","thumb":"images/avatar/thumb_7d41870512afee28d91.jpg","status":"HI4","isonline":""},{"friend_id":"66","name":"Another name","username":"regi","thumb":"images/avatar/thumb_d3fcc14e41c3a77aa712ae54.jpg","status":"Всем привет!","isonline":"avtbsl0a6dcelkq2bd578u1qt6"},{"friend_id":"2679","name":"My name","username":"Another","thumb":"images/avatar/thumb_41effb41eb1f969230.jpg","status":"","isonline":""}]}

// simple data store definition
Store = {items:{}};
NewStore = function(items){
    var store = Object.create(Store); 
    store.items = items || {}; 
    return store 
};
Store.put = function(id, item){this.items[id] = item;};
Store.get = function(id){ return this.items[id]; };
Store.remove = function(id){ delete this.items[id]; };
Store.clear = function(){ this.items = {}; };

// example
var chat = {
    data : {
        friends : NewStore()
    }
}

// after data loaded
chat.data.friends.clear();
for( var i = 0; i < DATA.users.length; i += 1 ){
    var user = DATA.users[i];
    chat.data.friends.put( user.friend_id, user );
}

getFriend = function(id){ return chat.data.friends.get( id ); }

var friend = getFriend(66);
console.log(friend.name);
console.log(friend.username);
console.log(friend.thumb);
```